# log4j how to specify log file relative path

Tags: java, apache, log4j

This is the log file for my log4j

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, FILE

    log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.FILE.file=/Applications/apache-tomcat-8.0.24/logs/myLog.log
    log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true
    log4j.appender.FILE.Encoding=UTF-8
    log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=10MB
    log4j.appender.FILE.MaxBackupIndex=10
    log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c:%L - %m%n
```

As you see, i specify the location of the log file like:

> Application/bla bla bla

That works good when I deploy on Mac, but sometimes, I deploy on windows, so I have to change that location to

> C:/bla bla bla

is there any way to make the path relative? I would like to create my custom log file **always** in the **logs folder** of apache on the server regardless of the operating system

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK relative paths are working on Windows like on other OS. The point is, when you use relative path it is relative to the current working directory of the running process.

Comment: What is your setup ? *Apache httpd* server with tomcat connector or plain, standalone *Apache tomcat* server ?

Comment: @PeterMmm it is apache tomcats, the portable server

Comment: @PeterMmm how can I use the relative please? I deploy by copying the war to the web app folder, while the logs folder is in the same level as the web app folder, kindly help

Answer (score 2):

When you deploy a web app into tomcat the *servlet code* runs in the JVM instance of tomcat. So all relative paths are relative to the current working directory (CWD) of the tomcat process.

The "standard" CWD is `%CATALINA_HOME%\bin`. To write into tomcat's log folder you logfile prefix should be `../logs/` like `../logs/myapp`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use maven, you can do:

[resource filtering](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html)

Comment: The log file is identified on the log4j configuration file

Comment: yes, and in the  log4j configuration file you can use a variable/placeholder, which is filled by resource filtering, depending in the system you are building for